# Need advice working with a button/switch

Tags: power-supply, power, switches, button

I'm using two [14.8 V Li-po batteries](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09JSC88TF) each to power [frequency generators](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NRH95AY) that are connected to piezo speakers.

I plan on adding XT60 connectors to the wires of the frequency generator so that the power supplies can be easily disconnected/connected when charging is needed.

For the button/switch: My idea is that once it's triggered, the generators emit ultrasonic frequency. What do you think is the best way to configure the button/switch?

I'm not sure how I could make it so that the button is connected to both units and maintains an even voltage input from the power supplies.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify the purpose of the button/switch a little more, I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Would a simple two-position DPDT toggle switch work here?

Comment: Do you just want one switch/button to turn on both systems and they stay on until switched/pressed again? As in the comments and answers a DPST is adequate for this.  DP meaning "double pole", (or two separate sections) so each battery/generator wire set is kept separate.  For a push button you often need to specify that you want a latching type (to stay on or off).  Be sure the switch/button is rated for the current you are switching.

Answer (score 1):

A DPST switch may be wired as shown below.

[image]

Operating it will switch on / switch off the generators together.

Answer (score 0):

You should add more to your question, like a sketch or a schematic of how exactly do you want to wire them up. 
I have just answered a question about two diodes between two supplies with one load, see if it can help in your situation: 
[If multiple sources are parallel with the diode, why does the one with a higher voltage turn on?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/662430/if-multiple-sources-are-parallel-with-the-diode-why-does-the-one-with-a-higher)

Comment: I added a picture but I'm not sure if it helps. I guess my problem is I'm unsure how I should wire them up.

Comment: @popeye3024 It is unclear what are you trying to accomplish. Please expand upon the last sentence in your question. Don't be shy, use as many words as you need. :D